# How to get the image URL only from the whole <img> tag in following scenario?

Tags: php, arrays, image, associative-array, key-value

I've an associative array titled `$data` as follows:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
[student_image] => <img src="http://34.144.40.142/file/pic/photo/2015/02/02ff1a23db112db834b8f41748242bcb_240.png"  alt=""  width="180"  height="160"  class="photo_holder" />
)

    [1] => Array
        (
[student_image] => <img src="http://34.144.40.142/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/document/docx.png"  alt="" />
)
[2] => Array
        (
 [student_image] => <img src="http://34.144.40.142/file/pic/photo/2015/02/da46580276da5c3a31b75e8b31d35ddf_240.png"  alt=""  width="180"  height="160"  class="photo_holder" />
)
)
```

The actual array is very huge, here I've put in only the necessary data from array.
Now what I want is for every element of the array the key `[student_image]` I should get only the URL of the image, no imag tag and any other data. In short I want following output of above array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
[student_image] => http://34.144.40.142/file/pic/photo/2015/02/02ff1a23db112db834b8f41748242bcb_240.png
)

    [1] => Array
        (
[student_image] => http://34.144.40.142/theme/frontend/foxplus/style/default/image/document/docx.png"
)
[2] => Array
        (
 [student_image] => http://34.144.40.142/file/pic/photo/2015/02/da46580276da5c3a31b75e8b31d35ddf_240.png
)
)
```

How should I achieve this in best possible and optimum way for all the elements of an array `$data`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this:

```
   //$data is your array
    $data = array_map(function($elem){
       //$elem is each elemet  of you array
       return array('student_image' => preg_replace('/<img\ssrc="([^"]+)".+$/','$1',$elem['student_image']));
    },$data);
```

Comment: What does $elem here? What should I use in case of $data array of mine? Can you please improvise your answer so that the change should get affect to the key [student_image] of $data array?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to extract the urls

```
// $data is your existing array with img tags
$urls = array();
foreach ($data as $key => $value){
    foreach ($value as $key1 => $img) {
        preg_match('/<img[^>]*src="([^"]*)"[^>]*\/>/', $img, $srcmatch);
        $urls[$key][$key1] = $srcmatch[1];
    }
}
// now $urls is having only image url and have same structure of $data,
// You may replace $urls with $data
var_dump($urls);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but nowhere the is a reference to the key [student_image] i your code. So could you please improvise your answer according to the $data array's [student_image] keys?

Comment: you have a two-dimensional array, so need an extra foreach loop to parse. please have a look at the modified code.